# Check for layout change of a pivot using vba

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I want to know if there is a way to loop through all pivot tables in a workbook and check if the layout of the pivot-table has been changed in any manner (new fields inserted, report filters added / removed, etc.) Is this possible?

Or if someone changes anything in a pivot (layout related, not the selection), then I want a flag to be toggled.

Please let me know your expert comments.

Thanks
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a bit longer than possible to put it in comment. So:

1. you can loop through all pivot tables (PTs), but keep in mind that PT is a worksheet object. In fact you need to loop through all Worksheets and than all PT in each separate Worksheet (loop in loop)
2. to check if PT changed you need to be able to compare- 'what was before' and 'what is now'. I don't find it very easy.
3. However, you could try to use any of Workbook PivotTable-related event to control all PTs. You could try to remember time when each of PT was changed or updated. But still, it would be difficult to check what has changed.